# Laravel 5 on failed request return back with model data

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

**EDIT**
This issue has been solved, but I don't understand why the answer worked.
I would like to know why it didnt work.
Is there some one who could explain me?

---

**Original question**
I am stuck on my settings form, my problem is that at the settings form you can enter some email settings but you can also change your password.

The email settings and password reset works and my form fills it self with the data of the current user. **But** when the form validation fails it redirecteds me back to the form without the form data.

I am not sure if I made myself clear, but this code below will explain it.

**ChangeUserSettingRequest.php**

```
class ChangeUserSettingsRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        if (\Auth::check()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * WHEN THIS VALIDATION FAILS IT GOES BACK TO SETTINGS.BLADE.PHP 
     * BUT IT DOES NOT KEEP THE SETTINGS DATA IN THE FORM
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'current_password' => 'sometimes|required_with:password',
            'password' => 'required_with:current_password|min:8|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password',
        ];
    }

}
```

**settings.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::model($settings, array('url' => route('store.settings'), 'class' => 'col s12')) !!}

    <p>@lang('forms.info.settings')</p>

    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
        {!! Form::checkbox('info_mail', 0, false, ['id' => 'info_mail']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('info_mail', Lang::get('forms.newsletter'), ['for' => 'info_mail']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
        {!! Form::checkbox('message_notification', 0, false, ['id' => 'message_notification']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('message_notification', Lang::get('forms.messages'), ['for' => 'message_notification']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
        {!! Form::checkbox('friend_notification', 0, false, ['id' => 'friend_notification']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('friend_notification', Lang::get('forms.friendrequest'), ['for' => 'friend_notification']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
        {!! Form::checkbox('item_notification', 0, false, ['id' => 'item_notification']) !!}
        {!! Form::label('item_notification', Lang::get('forms.reactiononitem'), ['for' => 'item_notification']) !!}
    </div>

    @if ($settings and $settings->google_maps !== null)
        <div class="settings-explain">
            <p class="margin-top-20">@lang('forms.info.companysettings')</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
            {!! Form::checkbox('type', 0, false, ['id' => 'type']) !!}
            {!! Form::label('type', Lang::get('forms.companytype'), ['for' => 'type']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
            {!! Form::checkbox('google_maps', 0, false, ['id' => 'google_maps']) !!}
            {!! Form::label('google_maps', Lang::get('forms.companymap'), ['for' => 'google_maps']) !!}
        </div>
    @endif

    <div class="settings-explain">
        <p class="margin-top-20">@lang('forms.info.changepassword')</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        {!! Form::label('current_password', $errors->has('current_password') ? $errors->first('current_password') : Lang::get('forms.currentpassword'), ['for' => 'current_password']) !!}
        {!! Form::password('current_password', ['class' => $errors->has('current_password') ? 'invalid' : '']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        {!! Form::label('password', $errors->has('password') ? $errors->first('password') : Lang::get('forms.newpassword'), ['for' => 'password']) !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => $errors->has('password') ? 'invalid' : '']) !!}
    </div>  
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? $errors->first('password_confirmation') : Lang::get('forms.repeatpassword'), ['for' => 'password_confirmation']) !!}
        {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? 'invalid' : '']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        {!! Form::button(Lang::get('forms.save'), ['class' => 'btn waves-effect waves-light', 'type' => 'submit', 'name' => 'Save']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**UserInfoController.php**

```
/**
 *  Function shows the settings form
 */
public function showSettings() 
{
    $title = Lang::get('titles.settings');
    $user_id = Auth::User()->id;

    $settings = $this->settings->getUserSettings($user_id);
    $companySettings = $this->companySettings->getSettings($user_id);

    if ($companySettings) {
        $settings->type = $companySettings->type;
        $settings->google_maps = $companySettings->google_maps;
    }

    return view('pages.users.settings', ['title' => $title])->with(compact('settings'));
}

/**
 *  Function stores the setting changes
 *
 *  ChangeUserSettingsRequest makes sure that the request is valid
 */
public function storeSettings(ChangeUserSettingsRequest $request)
{
    $id = Auth::User()->id;
    $success = $this->settings->handleStoreSettingsRequest($request);

    // Checks if user has company settings
    $hasCompanySettings = $this->companySettings->checkForSettings($id);

    // If user has company settings
    if ($hasCompanySettings === true) {
        // Update company settings
        $this->companySettings->updateSettings($request);
    }

    if ($success === true) {

        /* Get translated message */
        $message = Lang::get('toast.settingsstored');
        return Redirect::route('user.profile', array(Auth::User()->permalink))->withMessage($message);
    }

    $settings = $this->settings->getUserSettings($id);

    /* Get translated message */
    $message = Lang::get('forms.error.wrongpassword');

    /* This works and the form is filled with the correct data after it  redirects me back */
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(array('current_password' => $message))->withSettings($settings);
}
```

**Request.php**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
abstract class Request extends FormRequest {

    //

}
```

So my problem is that in my **UserInfoController** I redirect back and it has the good data but when my **ChangeUserSettingsRequest** redirects me back the form is empty.

Does anyone know why ChangeUserSettingsRequest does not send the data back?

- I am not talking about the password data but about the email settings.
- I do not want to make a costum validator as I think this should be posible.

**Please note: when the validation fails, the function `storeSettings` will not be executed at all**

Comment: try replacing '->withSettings($settings);' with '->withInputs();' in controller

Comment: @pinkalvansia The part in the controller works fine. Its just that the the ````ChangeUserSettingRequest```` will be executed first. If that fails the request never reaches the controller. So when the ````ChangeUserSettingRequest```` fails it should send me back to the form with the form data.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `dump($request->input())` in the `showSettings()` method after the `ChangeUserSettingsRequest` fails?

Comment: @Björn In Laravel 5 when the ````ChangeUserSettingsRequest```` fails it never reaches the controller. It will automatically send you back to the form.

Comment: Yes i know, `showSettings` method is where the form is rendered right? if you `dump($request->input())` there you can see all the input data laravel send back from the ValidationRequest.

Comment: @Björn Alright I will try it as soon as I can (after work) And update the question with the result. But I assume it is empty.

Comment: @Björn i added this  ````ChangeUserSettingsRequest $request```` as a parrameter of showSettings, but when I execute the form it gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

The formRequest should have handled it correctly but no idea why it did not.
I found the solution when looking trough the file formRequest.php
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php

I had to **override** the **response function** and it works now!
To only thing that I had to add to my `ChangeUserSettingsRequest` was this

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

The only difference is that I don't send the input fields back, little strange that this works but I am glad that it is solved now.

Comment: Could you just extend FormRequest then instead of Request? Would that also solve the issue?

Comment: @JonasHartmann I updated the question. But this didnt help cause the class Request extends formRequest.

Answer (score 4):

On failure return them back to the page with their input data (withInput())

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['current_password' => $message])->withInput($request->except('password'));
```

For more information see the Laravel docs pertaining to requests... http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

Comment: As you can see at the bottom of the file ````UserInfoController```` I am already doing something like that, not exactly but it works the same. My problem is that when the ````ChangeUserSettingsRequest```` fails it redirects me back directly so it never reaches the **controller** if it did reach the controller I wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: I have rewarded you the bounty as you have given my some kind of answer. It didnt solved my problem directly but I think this answer will help other people in the future.